# Chatserver. what happens to read an write buffer when ..?

Tags: sockets, networking

A TCP Chatserver uses polling method for a concurrent service. Client A is sending huge amounts of data constantly. Chatserver tries to send the data from client A to client B and C. But, client B and C is not reading from its read buffer. What happens to the read and write buffer for chatserver, client A, client B and client C.
There are 2 cases
1. Chatserver has blocking sockets.
2. Chatserver has non blocking sockets.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about TCP, the receiver's socket receive buffer fills up, so the sender's socket send buffer fills up, so the sender is either blocked (in blocking mode) or returned -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` in non-blocking mode.

If you're talking about UDP the datagrams are dropped.